# Broadcast message from terminal to locally logged in user

Tags: command-line, broadcasting

Here is what I am trying to do. Kids are on Ubuntu box watching movies, youtube, etc. I am on my windows box doing whatever. Since kids have headphones implanted into their ears, I want to log into terminal and send a broadcast message of some sort to them to get their attention or give them a message. I already know how to log into terminal remotely to work on the box while they are playing around.
I have seen a few options like "Wall" or "Write" but, those only seem to work on terminal logins. I can send messages to my test account logged into through the terminal but, nothing goes out to the local user sitting in front of the monitor. 
What are my options? For the most part, I would like a window to pop up with whatever message I am trying to deliver that will interrupt what they are doing when youtube or whatever is full-screen.
Thoughts? Suggestions? Advice?

Comment: Do you know your kid's password ?

Comment: No, I do not. I could be a butthead and log them off, I know how to do that remotely. I only reserve that meanness for when they cop an attitude and get grounded from the PC for a while.

Comment: Posted an answer , please review

Comment: How are you logging to the remote machine by the way? `ssh`? Else?

Comment: SSH. I use Putty from my box to get in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grant access

```
xhost +local:
```

or disable access control, clients can connect from any host **(bad idea, but seems to be ok in your network)**

```
xhost +
```

Now you can do this from your remote connection:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xmessage -center " THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE"
```

Bellow is a little demo. I have shared session between TTY1 and GUI terminal. As you can see, there's no environmental variable set for `DISPLAY`, thus that terminal is as if I was working in TTY1.  The command above temporarily sets the `DISPLAY` variable, thus making xmessage appear on  the xserver instance on that display.

[image]

I tried doing that same thing with `notify-send` however that didn't seem to work.

**EDIT**

`xmessage` is a bit small. What I'd prefer is to use `zenity` dialog. For instance,

`DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info --text=" THIS IS ZENITY INFO DIALOG "`

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. I ran into a snag though. When running the xmessage command, I get:"Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 Can't open display:0:

Comment: What about `zenity` ?

Comment: When running the zenity command, I get "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key ** (zenity:4200): WARNING *: Count not open X display   Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key (zenity:4200): gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

Comment: Take a look: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199892/85039

Comment: Ok. Hmmm.... Trying export DISPLAY=desktop:0 method, if I replace "desktop" with the IP address, I get a message saying, "Can't open display: 192.168.1.102.

Comment: @KC5SDY I'm going to install `ssh` server to my machine and play around with it. I'll report back if I find anything, but so far that's the best I can offer

Comment: @KC5SDY well, if I `ssh localhost` , it still works with the commands I posted in the answer. I don't know . . . .

Comment: There was a comment in the link that mentioned changing the x server's configuration to allow remote IP connections. Is that different than the remoting in I am doing now?

Comment: @KC5SDY `$DISPLAY` is set based on the actual X / screen(s) configuration, and might not be `:0` (e.g. for me it's `:0.0`). Without randomly guessing, just get to your kids' workstation and run `echo $DISPLAY` in Terminal in the current X session to get the actual `$DISPLAY` value, see if the actual value differs from `:0`

Comment: @kos good point. The who command can show users logged in on specific display. I don't think it's needed to run echo $DISPLAY

Comment: Running Who, it shows :0

Comment: I had to pry my daughter away from her show and run "xhost +local:" locally. Now, I am bug the crap out of her with messages. She got all my test messages. Crazy question, am I going to have to run "xhost +local:" again after a reboot or anything or is that permanent until changed?

Comment: Thought you would enjoy this. I installed a Putty like app on my tablet. I walked by, stopped long enough for her to look up, tapped SEND. The look on her face was priceless when she read the message! I can say we have a winner!!!!

Comment: Lol she's probably thinking "my dad is a hacker !". Glad we helped to find a solution for you man

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to create pop-up on their screen, it would be easiest to:

1) Start a program (I would use a Perl script) when your kids logon. Put it in the background. The Perl script should listen for a `TCP` connection on some unused port above `1024` and below `65536`, say port `12345`. When it receives a message (over `TCP` port `12345`), it can generate the pop-up, and wait for the next line.

2) On Windows, use `putty` to connect to TCP port 12345 on the Ubuntu server, and type your message.

Comment: Interesting. I like that idea. I do not know anything about putting together a script like that, much less getting it to run when they login.

Comment: That's a nice idea, +1, however I'd be interested in seeing a Perl implementation of this as well, maybe you can add a very brief example just to showcase the method?

Answer (score 0):

If it’s a short simple message that you want, you could use `notify-send`. This will create a short-lived alert message in the top right of the screen (in the same style that Thunderbird uses to alert you to new mail, or Filezilla uses to alert you that a long-running operation is complete).

```
notify-send "message text here"
```

or

```
notify-send "title here" "message text here"
```

or, if you *really* want their attention,

```
notify-send "title here" "message text here" -i face-angry
```

which will put an angry face (there’s a surprise!) before the message. There are various icons you can use. To see the list available on your computer, enter `ls /usr/share/icons/gnome/32x32/emotes/`.

Comment: This would be indeed a good solution, however IME specifying a `DISPLAY` value (at least over `ssh`) is necessary, I think you should add that